# Scaling centered CSS-background SVG-image proportionally to viewport without cropping

Tags: css, svg, background-image

I would like to display a SVG-circle (it's in a CSS-background) this way: it should scale to the available space of the viewport without being cropped. And, it should be centered horizontally and vertically in the viewport as well.

This is my code so far:

```css
div {
  background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml, %3Csvg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' viewBox='0 0 500 500' preserveAspectRatio='xMidYMid meet' style='position: absolute; left: 0; top: 0; width: 100%25;'%3E%3Ccircle cx='250' cy='250 ' r='249' style='stroke: %23000000; fill:none;'/%3E%3C/svg%3E");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: contain;
  background-position: center center;
  height: 99vh;
  width: 99vh;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div></div>
</body>
```

Unfortunately, it is not centered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's centered to the div, but the height and width are both specified in `vh` units, making the div a square that doesn't stretch the width of the viewport. Change the width declaration to use `vw` instead.

```css
div {
  background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml, %3Csvg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' viewBox='0 0 500 500' preserveAspectRatio='xMidYMid meet' style='position: absolute; left: 0; top: 0; width: 100%25;'%3E%3Ccircle cx='250' cy='250 ' r='249' style='stroke: %23000000; fill:none;'/%3E%3C/svg%3E");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: contain;
  background-position: center center;
  height: 99vh;
  width: 99vw;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div></div>
</body>
```

Comment: If I put your code into a clean HTML document and view it in firefox, then, if viewport width exceedes ca. 1020px, the circle doesn't scale anymore and looses centering  (it's displayed left aligned). In Safari and Chrome it's working, but there are annoying scrollbars visible, that let you scroll a few pixels horizontally and vertically …

Comment: It works as intended in Firefox for me. Most browsers add margin to the body element by default that you'll need to remove to prevent the scrollbars.

Comment: OK, thanks! Now it works in Firefox as well. Had some aggressive caching on the webserver.